# How to get parents hashes during open merge process?

Tags: git

I have open merge process. Nothing commited yet. There may be conflicts.
I'd like to write a script that does something automatically. The script needs hashes of all parents involved in current merge. How to extract this data from git?

Comment: Do you have to do other things manually there? I mean, maybe just make/start the merge inside the script, so that you have the pointers upfront? Of course, that approach works for only limited set of cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HEAD` stays the same during merge. `MERGE_HEAD` is set to point to the other commit during conflict resolution.

`git help merge` says:

> When it is not obvious how to reconcile the changes, the following happens:
>
> 1. The HEAD pointer stays the same.
> 2. The MERGE_HEAD ref is set to point to the other branch head.
> 3. ...

To get commit hashes, use `git rev-parse`:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
git rev-parse MERGE_HEAD
```